# How to make a smooth movement?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Tell me how to make a smooth movement of the object. At first, I used: `transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + 1.245, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);` but it's just teleportation. I need the object to move 1.245 in 0.3 seconds. How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

For a smooth transition, you need an interpolation method.

For example linear interpolation:

```
a * (1.0 - f) + b * f
```

where `a` and `b` are vectors and `f` is a floating point value between 0.0 and 1.0 (e.g. fraction of passed time).

You could use different interpolation methods too, for example smoothstep, hermite, catmull-rom or bezier cuves.

Unity documentation (with example): [Vector3.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html)

Comment: In Unity, the standard way of doing this is to use `Time.DeltaTime`, so in your answer, `f` would be `Time.DeltaTime`

Comment: @Zimano, no `f` is not `Time.deltaTime`. It is a value between 0 and 1 as a percentage of the full motion. There is nothing Unity special/standart about `Time.deltaTime`, it is just an universal way to do frame rate independent movement. In this case `Time.deltaTime` is one of multiple values needed to derive `f`.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for explaining! However, `Time.DeltaTime` is frame-rate dependent. But I understand what you mean in that it is used for framerate *independent* movement.

Answer (score 0):

you moving your object with position and its just using for teleporting character 
you can use rigidbody or character controller
 for example

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody rigidbody;
    private void Start()
    {
        // Befor runing the game you must add Rigidbody component to your character gameobject
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    float moveSpeed = 1.245f;
    private void Update()
    {
        float hor = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * moveSpeed; // x axis
        float ver = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * moveSpeed; // z axis
        float jump = Input.GetAxis("Jump") * moveSpeed; // y axis
        // velocity is a local position the character moveing to that
        rigidbody.velocity = new Vector3(x: hor, y: jump, z: ver);
    }
}
```

Comment: A `Rigidbody` is definitely not needed (or a prerequisite) to get smooth movement.

Answer (score 0):

For the best results (which the other answers don't discuss) you will need to move objects using `Time.DeltaTime` as a modifier. For your piece of code, this would be:

`transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x + (1.245 * Time.DeltaTime), transform.position.y, transform.position.z);`

This will multiply your "speed value" of 1.245 with the time that passed between frames. This will guarantee smooth movement.

For moving 1.245 units over 0.3 seconds, you will need to move `0.3 / 1.245` units per Update loop for 0.3 seconds.

Comment: Thank you, how can you limit travel time here? (For 0.3 seconds)

Comment: If it's easy, can you give an example of a code with a restriction?

Comment: @ReGeNs This will help you, the article shows how to do X for Y seconds. https://answers.unity.com/questions/1040630/do-something-for-10-sec.html Ignore the coroutine part for now.